# How do i Access GoogleApiClient in Different Activities

Tags: java, android

how do i access  Googleapiclient in different activities?how do i make it global so that it can be used in all activities
Can we pass it through intent ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass it via intent.  If it needs to be used across activities you either need to make a new one for each Activity or you need to make it owned by a Service that the activities then query for results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an application class. Its a singelton based class which you can access from almost everywhere.

Documentation for application class : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: thanku for your reply !!but can u give me an example about how can i use it